# Setting Top Margin within a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, nodes

I have two nodes which form boxes. One of them is the headline and the other one contains the information using `\itemize`. As there was a lot of space between the left border and the bullets I reduced the left margin. I would like to do the same with the top margin and don't know how. Maybe somebody here is able to help?

If there is a smoother way creating the picture of the boxes I would be happy to here it.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define block styles used later
\tikzstyle{hl} = [draw, text width=14em, fill=blue!80, text centered, 
    minimum height=3em, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{info} = [draw, text width=14em, fill=blue!20,  
    minimum height=3em, drop shadow, text centered, align = left
    ,execute at begin node={\setlength{\leftmargini}{1.1em}}]

\node at (0,0)     [hl]  (hl_tsd)      {Headline Text in Box};
\node at (0,-2.3)  [info] (info_tsd)   {\begin{itemize} \footnotesize
                                            \item Text item 1
                                            \item Text item 2
                                            \item Text item 3
                                        \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A node has the `inner ysep` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can consider `tcolorbox` for this kind of constructions instead of `TiKZ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep, topsep=0mm, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, width= 5cm, 
    colbacktitle=blue!80, colback =blue!20, top=1mm, bottom=1mm, left=1mm,
    title={Headline Text in Box}]
     \begin{itemize}
     \item Text item 1
     \item Text item 2
     \item Text item 3
     \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A pure Ti*k*Z solution. I assume that you after something like following?

[image: label=$\bullet$,]

Above image is produced by help of `shapes.multipart` Ti*k*Z library and `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tikzitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tikzitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  after=\vspace{1ex}
                  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
mpnv/.style = {% vertical multi part node
    rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw,   text width=14em,
    rectangle split part fill = {blue!30, white} }
                    ]

\node   [mpnv]  {\nodepart{one} Headline Text in Box\\
                 \nodepart{two} %\footnotesize
                            \begin{tikzitem} 
                        \item Text item 1
                        \item Text item 2
                        \item Text item 3
                            \end{tikzitem}
                 };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: as you can see, above MWE is quite different from yours.